# Can you see areas outside from inside an area of Darkness?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, combat

Lets say you're in an area of dim light (20% miss chance). You get in combat with some archers, and so cast [Darkness](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/darkness.html) on your weapon/holy symbol. This lowers the light in a 20ft radius, in this case to darkness (50% miss chance). Ignore low-light vision and Darkvision.

Can you still see your enemies (assuming they are > 20ft away)? If so, they would have 50% miss chance against you, but you would only have 20% miss chance attacking them.

Ps. I've read some similar questions, but they were all for other systems or not answered.

Comment: It seems that potential duplicate has probably got the bases covered here - I've considered answering this but I'd be repeating a smaller section of my answer from there. And it's for Pathfinder, too!

Comment: Same core question, but worded differently enough that I didn't find it. Also the accepted answer isn't quite as accurate as I would like, but I'll take it.